# save xslt output transformation in a file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have a "book.xml" and "book.xslt" the output has been set on text-mode, I don't want to load text file by browser because it is so heavy I need some code to save output text file in hard-drive. How I can implement this kind of transformation by c# ?

Comment: do you want to save the file on the user's machine, or do you want to save the file to the server?

Comment: I need save file on the server only.

Comment: was just about to post my answer, but it's the same as Kev's.. so there is no need to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(@"c:\book.xslt");
xslt.Transform(@"c:\book.xml", @"c:\output.txt");
```

Obviously your paths will need to be updated to match your particular scenario, for example:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/book.xslt"));
xslt.Transform(Server.MapPath("~/book.xml"), Server.MapPath("~/output.txt") );
```

This will read your XSL file from the root of the site and transform `/book.xml` and save it to `/output.txt`.

You can find out more about the `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` class here:

> [System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` class.

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(Server.MapPath("~/book.xslt"));
transform.Transform(Server.MapPath("~/book.xml"), Server.MapPath("~/output.xml"));
```

(Note: this assumed all the documents are stored in the root of the web application)

Answer (score 0):

By using xmwwriter and xdocument like so:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

public void xmltest(string xmlFilePath, string xslFilePath, string outFilePath) 
{
    var doc = new XPathDocument(xmlFilePath);
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outFilePath);
    var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();

    // The following two lines are only needed if you need scripting.
    // Because of security considerations read up on that topic on MSDN first.
    var settings = new XsltSettings();
    settings.EnableScript = true;

    transform.Load(xslFilePath,settings,null);

    transform.Transform(doc, writer);

}
```

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742.aspx

regards

Comment: There's an overload on the Transform method that already write's directly to a file without having to use a writer. Under the bonnet it already uses an XmlWriter.

Comment: Also, if you do use an `XmlWriter` directly, you should wrap it in a `using` statement.

Comment: ty. what about the xpathdocument and xslcompiledtransform? should the be wrapped inside the using as well?

Comment: Beware that your output of the transformation must be a well-formed xml document other XmlWriter is not the right choice.